# How to make one part of activity always visible on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've created ListActivity and other Activities, which I would like to be displayed when I click item from ListActivity. My problem is that I don't know how to do it in the same window, so that the ListActivity will stay always visible, while other part of the window will change based on the pressed element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Activities, I would implement your functionality in Fragments. They allow for increased modularity of an application, and will allow for the functionality that you desire, at runtime they can be "swapped out" with inside your ListActivity.

Reference to a thorough overview of Fragments on the Android Developer website: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 5):

You would have to have only one activity, such as by converting "other Activities" into fragments that are displayed by the `ListActivity`.